# How to use fingerprint sensor to authenticate users in android?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-fingerprint-api

> I want to develop an app that uses the fingerprint sensor to authenticate the user.
>
> I searched for tutorials and I found some.
>
> but can I use a special fingerprint for my app?
>
> I mean that I want my app to has the ability to save a fingerprint and use it after that without any need for using the fingerprints saved and used by the system.
>
> Is it possible ? and if it is how can I do such a thing ?

Answer (score 0):

An Open Source Sample project by Google is already available on GitHub to implement the FingerPrint Sensor for your application. Please refer to [this link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog) and check if fits your requirement.